# assign non-integer value to integer variable in C

Tags: c, gnu

I am referring to GNU c tutorial it says assign non-integer value to integer variable will  generate compile time error what exactly the error is,any example?? 
i tried

int a='A';

int a=2.323;

all are fine

what else could be to justify the statement??

Comment: Don't know what tutorial that is, but it's clearly wrong. But did it say warning instead of error?

Comment: Where did you read that? Perhaps provide the link?

Comment: `'A'` has type `int` in C. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars)

Comment: http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Type-errors.html#Type%20errors

Comment: but the statement seems logical is there any example that helps me understand it

Comment: int a="A"; compiled without any error but with warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
and printf prints some random integer value to stdout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases some conversions are being made. You can use -Wconversion in gcc for example to warn for implicit conversion.

(see [Why assignment of double to int does not trigger gcc warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999172/why-assignment-of-double-to-int-does-not-trigger-gcc-warnings))

One example that does not compile is

```
struct account {
   int account_number;
   char *first_name;
   char *last_name;
   float balance;
};

struct account s;

int a=s;//breaks
```

The error message is in MSVC100 for example.

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'account' to 'int'
>
> No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this
>   conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Comment: yeah it gives error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘int’ using type ‘struct account’

Comment: ok so choose it as the correct answer (some people downvoted it without knowing what they were doing)

Comment: but non-integer value could be other values too other than assigning the struct itself to a variable??

Comment: some automatic conversions are made in this case for example an enum is an int so you can assign it to an int

Comment: what else could be other "non-integer " values if i were to assign it to a int variable to check for errors compiler generate

Comment: string for example would break

Comment: yeah but it gives warning as i mentioned not kind of error we can say specifically